# preg_replace и php 5.5

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Поставил один хороший движок, но разрабатывался он под php 5.4.

Теперь постоянно ругается на вот эту строчку:

```
$source_content = preg_replace($search.'e', "'"
   . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
   . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\\0', \"\n\")) .'"
   . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
   . "'"
   , $source_content);
```

Прошу помощи у вас ее переделать в `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 1):

Почти ничего не меняется:

1. Убираем модификатор `e`;
2. Меняем строку замены на `function ($m) { return /*строка замены */ }`;
3. Внутри строки замены меняем ссылки вида `\\n` на `$m[n]`, где n - соответствующая цифра.

Получается так:

```
$source_content = preg_replace_callback($search, 
   function ($m) { return "'"
       . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
       . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count(${m[0]}, \"\n\")) .'"
       . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
       . "'"
   }, $source_content);
```